# (Next.js Typescript) Block-scoped variable used before its declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I'm making an admin website, but I got the error `Block-scoped variable used before its declaration.`
I will explain it via image and code.
by the way this is my first time using StackOverflow

**the error message:**

- Block-scoped variable 'page' used before its declaration.
- Variable 'page' is used before being assigned.
- Block-scoped variable 'pageSize' used before its declaration.
- 'pageSize' is declared here.

**tech I used:**

- next.js 14
- react-query

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.35.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.35.3",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.10.6",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/node": "20.3.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.12",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.15.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.5",
    "apexcharts": "^3.42.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.5",
    "formik": "^2.4.3",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "heroicons": "^2.0.18",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "next": "^14.0.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.4",
    "next-nprogress-bar": "^2.1.2",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.16",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "react-calendar": "^4.6.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.16.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.3.1",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-tabs": "^6.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.65.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.6.13",
    "typescript": "5.1.3",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.15",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "postcss": "^8.4.29",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

**this is ziarah.section.tsx:**

```
"use client";

interface Props {}

const ZiarahSection: NextPage<Props> = ({}) => {
  const { useGetZiarah, useDeleteZiarah } = useZiarahModule(page, pageSize);
  const {
    data: dataZiarah,
    isError: isErrorZiarah,
    isFetching: isFetchingZiarah,
    isLoading: isLoadingZiarah,
    refetch: refetchZiarah,
  } = useGetZiarah();
  const { isLoading: isLoadingDelete, mutate } = useDeleteZiarah();
  const onDelete = async (id: any) => {
    mutate(id, {
      onSuccess: () => {
        return refetchZiarah();
      },
    });
  };

  // const totalRecords = dataZiarah?.pagination?.total;
  const {
    page,
    pageSize,
    totalPages,
    isCanPrevious,
    isCanNext,
    setPage,
    setPageSize,
  } = usePagination({
    initialPage: 1,
    initialPageSize: 10,
    // totalRecords: totalRecords || 0,
    data: dataZiarah,
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <SecondTopNav
        navigateTo="ziarah/tambah-ziarah"
        title="Ziarah"
        totalData={dataZiarah?.pagination.total ?? 0}
        isLoading={isLoadingDelete || isLoadingZiarah}
      />

      <section className="mb-5 grid w-full grid-cols-2 grid-rows-3 gap-4">
        {isErrorZiarah ? (
          <p>Terjadi kesalahan</p>
        ) : isFetchingZiarah || isLoadingZiarah ? (
          Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="w-full rounded-[15px]">
              <Skeleton
                height={200}
                baseColor="#9FA1B5"
                highlightColor="#1c1e3b"
              />
            </div>
          ))
        ) : dataZiarah?.pagination.total === 0 ? (
          <p>Tidak ada data</p>
        ) : (
          dataZiarah?.data.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <ZiarahCard
                data={item}
                isLoading={isLoadingDelete || isLoadingZiarah}
                key={item.id}
                onClickDelete={() => onDelete(item.id)}
              />
            );
          })
        )}
      </section>

      <section>
        <PaginationMenu
          firstPageButtonIsDisabled={isCanPrevious}
          previousPageButtonIsDisabled={isCanPrevious}
          nextPageButtonIsDisabled={isCanNext}
          lastPageButtonIsDisabled={isCanNext}
          previousPageButtonOnClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}
          nextPageButtonOnClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}
          firstPageButtonOnClick={() => setPage(1)}
          lastPageButtonOnClick={() => setPage(totalPages)}
          inputPageOnChange={(e) => setPage(Number(e.target.value))}
          inputValue={page}
          pageFrom={page}
          pageTo={totalPages}
          currentPageSize={pageSize}
          pageSizeOnClick={(size: number) => setPageSize(size)}
        />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ZiarahSection;
```

**ziarah.service.ts:**

```
const useZiarahModule = () => {
  const { toastError, toastSuccess, toastWarning } = useNotification();
  const axiosClient = useAxiosAuth();

  const useGetZiarah = (page = 1, pageSize = 10) => {
    console.log('page', page)
    console.log('pagesize', pageSize)
    const getZiarah = async (): Promise<ZiarahPaginationResponse> => {
      return axiosClient
        .get(`/lokasi_ziarah?page=${page}&pageSize=${pageSize}`)
        .then((res) => res.data);
    };
    const { data, isError, isFetching, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery({
      queryKey: ["lokasi_ziarah"],
      queryFn: () => getZiarah(),
    });

    return { data, isError, isFetching, isLoading, refetch };
  };

  return {
    useGetZiarah,
  };

export default useZiarahModule;
```

**this is my hook, usePagination.ts:**

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface PaginationHookOptions {
  initialPage: number;
  initialPageSize: number;
  // totalRecords: number | undefined;
  data: any;
}

interface PaginationHookResult {
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
  totalPages: number;
  isCanPrevious: boolean;
  isCanNext: boolean;
  setPage: (page: number) => void;
  setPageSize: (pageSize: number) => void;
}

const usePagination = ({
  initialPage,
  initialPageSize,
  // totalRecords,
  data
}: PaginationHookOptions): PaginationHookResult => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(initialPage);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(initialPageSize);
  const [isCanPrevious, setIsCanPrevious] = useState(true);
  const [isCanNext, setIsCanNext] = useState(true);

  const totalRecords = data?.pagination?.total || 0;
  const totalPages = totalRecords ? Math.ceil(totalRecords / pageSize) : 1;

  const isCanPreviousPage = () => {
    if (page > 1) {
      setIsCanPrevious(false);
    } else {
      setIsCanPrevious(true);
    }
  };

  const isCanNextPage = () => {
    if (page >= totalPages) {
      setIsCanNext(true);
    } else {
      setIsCanNext(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    isCanPreviousPage();
    isCanNextPage();
  }, [page, totalPages]);


  return {
    page,
    pageSize,
    totalPages,
    isCanPrevious,
    isCanNext,
    setPage,
    setPageSize,
  };
};

export default usePagination;
```

**so the error is appear in ziarah.section.tsx:**

```
const {
    data: dataZiarah,
    isError: isErrorZiarah,
    isFetching: isFetchingZiarah,
    isLoading: isLoadingZiarah,
    refetch: refetchZiarah,
  } = useGetZiarah(page, pageSize);
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyRGv.png)

The problem is that both variables depend on each other.

I've tried declaring the variable 'useGetZiarah' first and then the 'usePagination' variable, but I'm still getting errors. When I tried it the other way around, the error persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the dependency issue would be to move the `page` and `pageSize` states out of `usePagination` and into `ZiarahSection` and set their initial values to 1 and 10. This way `usePagination` doesn't even need to be a hook. (I renamed it `getPagination`.)

```js
interface PaginationHookOptions {
  data: any;
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
};

// not a hook anymore
const getPagination = ({
  data,
  page,
  pageSize
}: PaginationHookOptions): PaginationHookResult => {
  const isCanPrevious = page > 0;
  const isCanNext = page >= totalPages;

  const totalRecords = data?.pagination?.total || 0;
  const totalPages = totalRecords ? Math.ceil(totalRecords / pageSize) : 1;

  return {
    totalPages,
    isCanPrevious,
    isCanNext,
  };
};
```

But apart from this there are some other issues in your code. React Query provides a hook with built in pagination called [useInfiniteQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useInfiniteQuery), you should use it instead. Then your code will be greatly simplified.